# javascript evaluation in Microsoft.jScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate

Tags: c#

```
var x = "var dom = null;

try {
    dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) // parse error ..
        window.alert(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText);
} catch (e) { dom = null; ";

try {
    var str = Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(x,Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine());
     MessageBox.Show(str.ToString());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

This following error gives me the error which is given below variable 'window' has not been declared.

This project is the windowsform application which is developed into C#.net.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I got the solution which is given below

`var wsShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            wsShell.Popup(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText, 0, Title);`